# 'No such file or directory' when I use python subprocess.run('docker build ...')

Tags: python, docker

In ubuntu18.04

I am writing a python script to build a docker image then do other things, the `main.py` is here:

```
from subprocess import run
run('docker build --rm -f "Dockerfile" -t test:latest .')
...
```

Then error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 403, in run
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'docker build --rm -f "Dockerfile" -t test:latest .': 'docker build --rm -f "Dockerfile" -t test:latest .'
```

While the `Dockerfile` and `main.py` are put together and it is fine to run the build command in the shell directly.

Comment: try to add `shell=True` as argument. Needed to run commands as string, or split the arguments and pass a list.

Comment: thank you, it works. But I wonder why it works without `shell=True` on Windows?

Comment: on windows it's different, yes. The way to start the commands is OS dependent that's why. The best way is to split the arguments.